# Enable auditing only for a specific sharepoint library programatically - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How can I enable auditing for a specific SharePoint library in SharePoint 2010 through code?

Answer (score 1):

There is dedicated article:

[Activating Auditing Programmatically for a Single Document Library in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418730%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Its for WSS v3 but should work for SP 2010 as well.